# RASA X- Linux server instalation

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

i am creating a chat bot using rasa x

i installed rasa x in my linux server using [Server-Quick Install](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/installation-guide/#server-quick-install)

then installation completed and url generated.

but here how we  install rasa packages? or no need  ?

i added some stories, domain, nlu data , response

after adding this i tried training . but training not executing. it showing your model  training has failed.

1. how can i train my chat bot and get response ?
2. while using localhost i can access the response through

http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook

requset as
{
"sender": "Rasa",
"message": "How can i enter"
}

is it possible to access data through this in server also? i need  url for accessing response

[image]

Comment: Can you share the error with us

Comment: @Tarequzzaman Khan yes.. updated.

Answer (score 0):

Install rasa via

```
pip install rasa
```

then start the project with

```
rasa init
```

this will give you the needed project files.
then start rasa x from that folder.

Also the nature of the error is shown in the terminal you used to launch rasa x, not the GUI itself.

Comment: rasa installing failed in my server. I think isssue related my old server.